# Are the English words "essence" and "essential" related to the Spanish word "ser"?

Tags: english, etymology, spanish, cognates

I always think of the Spanish verb "ser" being related to "essence", which can be contrasted with the verb "estar", which is related to "state".

"Ser" is also a noun with various meanings including "being" as in "ser humano" = "human being", and "essence". There is also another Spanish word "esencia" meaning "essence".

But am I actually correct in thinking "ser" is related to "esencia", "essence", "essential", etc? Or is it just one more linguistic coincidence after all?

(I've checked Wiktionary and the Dicc. RAE but didn't find a full answer so I bring it here to the experts.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Some forms of *ser* are cognate with "essence", but *ser* itself is not.

*Ser* in Spanish is a "suppletive verb", which is missing some of its forms and has stolen them from other verbs to compensate. Compare English "go", which doesn't have the past-tense form *goed; instead, it's stolen the past form "went" from the unrelated verb "wend" (as in "wend your way").

*Ser* itself comes from Latin *sedēre* "to sit" (*). (*Estar* on the other hand is from *stāre* "to stand".) English has various cognates of *sedēre*, but "essence" isn't one of them.

However, forms such as the present-tense *soy, es, somos, son* come from the Latin *sum, es, sumus, sunt*: the present indicative of the verb *esse*, "to be". "Essence" and related words do come from *esse*; the participle ending *-nt-* was added to *esse* to form a word meaning "being". Thus "essence" is "that which is being", and "essential" is "related to essence", and so on.

As far as the noun *ser*, I'm afraid I don't know its etymology, but I'd assume it's related to the verb.

(*) The etymology I'm familiar with is *sedēre* > *seder* > *seer* > *ser*, though as pointed out in the comments it could also be from *esse* > *essere* > *esser* > *ser*. Most likely the two forms influenced each other, because there are some forms of *ser* that are definitely from *esse* and others that are definitely from *sedēre*.

Comment: Ser *itself comes from Latin* sedēre *"to sit".*  There is a counterargument that *ser* is cognate with Italian *essere*, at least partly.

Comment: "Essentia" is used by Quintilian. That is as classic as you can get.

Comment: For some speakers, it undoubtedly **is** related to _esse_ or _essere_; for others, undoubtedly it's not. There's 2000 years of history here, with millions of speakers, and trillions of usages, all of which are different. The idea that there is one source for a word like _ser_ is as silly as the idea that one mutation created human speech.

Comment: @fdb Didn't know that! Fixed.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Huh, I wasn't familiar with that argument. It does make sense, though the loss of initial /e/ seems odd to me without at least some influence from *sedēre*. Added a note!

Comment: It seems a bit odd that Iberian *ser* is considered to be from both *essere* and *sedere* even though *sentar* is also from *sedere*, while Venetian has *éser* and *sentar* and nobody disputes that *éser* is from *essere*.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer *sentar* isn't directly from *sedēre* though, is it? That came from the emphatic *sedentāre* < *sedens* "sitting", and shows the same pattern of *d* vanishing between vowels.

Comment: @Draconis Yes, but it's the same for Venetian and Iberian *sentar*, so why the differing explanations?  Also the total ellision of medial *d* in * sedentāre* is different, which is why it happened in Venetian too.

Answer (score 6):

As Draconis says, some conjugations of *ser* are cognate with Latin *esse* derived words in English, but not all. I made this chart (based on [this](http://spanishlinguist.us/tag/suppletion/) blog post) a while ago, it details which are which:

[image]

---

<sup>^ **Note for *ve***</sup>

<sup>In voseo dialects, the 2nd person sing. pos. (*vos*) imperative for *ir* is *andá* (from Latin *ambulare*). This is cognate with Spanish *andar*, Catalan *anar*, Italian *andare*, French *aller* (all meaning to go/to walk).</sup>

---

<sup>**Source**</sup>

- <sup>http://spanishlinguist.us/2017/02/why-ser-and-ir-are-so-irregular/</sup>